# How do I add a symbol in html?

Tags: html, tabs, symbols

I want to add a back link in html. Because my code makes a link open in a new tab I made my code close the current code. So I typed this:

```
      <a href="javascript:window.close();">↩ Back</a>
```

But it shows up with this: `â†© Back` not this: `↩` Now I'm wondering if you can't actually put symbols on to html.

If anyone knows the answer I will be very happy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the same symbol using Unicode. The html code is

`&#8629` you can add different symbols on HTML even emojis. More on on this [here.](https://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/arrows/) Hope this helps.

Comment: It works! But is there any website that has all these symbols?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters also has a good list

Answer (score 1):

`<meta charset="UTF-8">` to change your encoding? From [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_charset.asp). You might need a different encoding.

Comment: I don't see my symbol in the table, What now?

Comment: @Banana.html try one of the other answers?

Comment: I upvoted this because it's the only answer that actually addresses the problem instead of suggesting workarounds. However, next time don't disguise a W3Schools link as W3. TIA!

Comment: @MrLister, yeah my bad on that one

Answer (score 1):

One way to show a Unicode symbol in HTML would be to substitute it for its [character entity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity).

The character you're looking for in this case is either `&larrhk;`, `&hookleftarrow;`, `&#x021A9;` or `&#8617;`:

```html
<div>&larrhk;</div>
<div>&hookleftarrow;</div>
<div>&#x021A9;</div>
<div>&#8617;</div>
```

A full list of character entities can be found [here](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref) for reference.